# which one is a more scalable solution for managing image files

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, windows

I need to be able to support user image upload and download/view images.

here are my options.

1) **Store images in a sql database.**

I have seen this work for  a small setup. DB cost would go higher as the size increases.
backups would be easier. Can't take advantage of caching or CDN.

2) **Store images in a file system.**
I have seen this option being cumbersome in slightly larger than a small setup. Difficult to manage directories with huge number of files. Will have to come up with some hashing algorithm to make sure there are a few images in a directory and a directory contains only a few directories. Dont know if there is a limit in windows for creating a deep directory structure. Could use caching.

3) **Store images in nosql DB.**
Just throwing this one there. I am not too familiar with NoSql.

4) **Windows Azure storage/Amazon storage.**

Couple of things.
1) money is an important factor.
2) windows is preferred environment but linux/apache solutions are ok.

And one more thing. What would Facebook do? or does.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You should go with a hybrid solution.

Store your actual binary images on the filesystem, but use a database for image metadata. This gives you an easier medium with which to serve the files from - allowing for scalability and potentially speed of serving them, whilst also having the speed of a database for searching, filtering, etc.

I have seen various ways of implementing this.. but generally they are primary keys + mime type + directory tied to a file name / folder. For example, a photo in the `/simon-whitehead/albums/stackoverflow/` directory with the filename `1013.jpg` would have something like this as it's table in the database:

```
Id - 1013
Name - example.jpg
AlbumId - (Stackoverflow album id)
UserId - (my user id)
Lat - 37.81
Long - 144.96
Date - 7/10/2013
Mime type - image/jpeg
```

You may even have a junction table that joins tags to images (for searching). Then, you basically build the response like this:

```
file = getuser(userId).name / getalbum(albumId).name / getimage(imageid).name
```

EDIT: I see you've now added Azure. I will say that one company I worked for used Azure and they had fantastic experiences. I however didn't get much chance to have a look.. so I cannot give any advice on that.

Comment: Can you please expand on the last line? Also i have added one more option. Thanks

Comment: I have expanded a little bit. It gives you a basic outline of what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinvent the wheel.

[Image Resizing for .Net](http://imageresizing.net/) has pretty much everything you could think of. Caching, cloud plugins, API and a huge community + associated support.

There are a variety of methods to optimize performance and it's easy to switch from one provider to another say S3 to Azure; take a look at that product (it has a nuget package) if you have a chance.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not in Azure, it's better to save your files in a file system.
But if your project is already located in Azure, then you should better use blob's containers for storing your files.
Comparing where to store the files: in a database or in a file system , the answer is:
It's better to use a file system because it would work faster and your database won't grow up because of the tons of the images.